# On the density of colossally abundant numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Define $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} d$. A integer $n>1$ is said to be colossally abundant (CA) if there exists some exponent $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\varepsilon}} \geq \frac{\sigma(m)}{m^{1+\varepsilon}}$$ for every integer $m>1$. Let $p_{k} >20000$ be the largest prime factor of the CA number $n$. Is it necessarily true that $n \in [N_k, N_{k+1})$ where $N_j$ denotes the product of the first $j$ primes ?

P.S.: This result was stated without proof on page 206 of [http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Robin_1984.pdf](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Robin_1984.pdf), so either it's completely trivial or an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing the exact reference!

My translation of the relevant passage is: "Consequently, if $N_k \le n < N_{k+1}$, with $p_k \ge 20000$, we have: [displayed equation]. If $n\le N_{k_1}$ [note the subscript is $k_1$, which I missed earlier], we use the results calculated by computer in Proposition 3 of Section 3." In the first line of the proof (same page), Robin writes: "Let $N_k = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$ [he writes $p_k$ but surely that is a typo] and suppose that $p_k \ge 20000$ ($k\ge k_1$).", which I believe is the implicit definition of the integer $k_1$.

So I believe what is happening is:

- if $n$ is at most $N_{k_1}$, which is the product of all the primes up to $20000$, then the computer results are relevant;
- otherwise, there exists some integer $k\ge k_1$ such that $N_k \le n < N_{k+1}$, in which case the displayed equation is relevant.

In the OP, it is claimed that $n$ is colossally abundant and that $p_k$ is its largest prime factor; but I don't believe that either statement is necessarily true in the context of this remark. Rather, $n$ is any integer at all, and $p_k$ is only mentioned to help clarify what $N_k$ is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! By cases, do you mean $n\leq N_k$ and $n>N_k$ ? Note that every CA number $n>6$ is divisible by a square of some prime. Since $n$ has a prime factorisation of the form $2^{a_1}3^{a_2}\cdots {p_k}^{a_k}$ where $a_{i} \geq a_{i+1}$ for all $i \leq k-1$, it follows that $n>N_k$ for $p_{k} > 3$. Does this entail the inequality in the paper, that $n \in [N_{k}, N_{k+1})$ for $p_{k}  \geq 20000$ ?

Comment: So, is Robin is saying for $p_{k} \geq 20000$, the only possible cases are $n\leq N_k$ and $N_{k} < n <  N_{k+1}$ ? But he doesn't give any justification why $n$ can't be $\geq N_{k+1}$. Or is this rather trivial ?

Comment: I looked more closely at the page and edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for making the answer rigorous ! I don't quite understand French, so some parts of the paper were not very clear to me.